# Creating new Java FileSystem object returns IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, filesystems, gzip

I'm trying to iterate over a `.gz` file using the `FileSystem` class and the options offered by the classes of `java.nio.file` package. Following my code:

```
public void uncompress(Path archiveFile, Path destDir) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        ...
        
        Path archiveAbsPath = archiveFile.toAbsolutePath();
        URI archiveUri = archiveAbsPath.toUri();
        try (FileSystem archiveFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archiveUri, null)) {
        ...
        }
```

The `archiveUri` variable will hold a value like `file:///data/sites/printserver/cache/templates/localhost/trees/0.0.1.19/print-template.TREES.0.0.1.19.tar.gz`. When the code initializes the variable `archiveFileSystem` it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/', 
    Stack trace: [com.r3gis.printserver.printing.CreateFromTemplateCommand.execute(CreateFromTemplateCommand.java:105), 
    com.r3gis.printserver.main.PrintProcessor.processPrintJob(PrintProcessor.java:98), 
    com.r3gis.printserver.main.PrintQueueListener.receiveMessage(PrintQueueListener.java:92), 
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), 
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62), 
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), 
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566), 
    org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171), 
    org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137), 
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043), 
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)]
```

To me, it seems that it complains about the correctness of the `URI`, but I did not understand where the error is.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "I'm trying to iterate over a .gz file using the FileSystem class"? A GZip file is not a ZIP file and can contain only one file. The usual way to read GZip files is by using [GZIPInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html).

Comment: Solved. I was creating a not valid gzip file. Thanks for the help.